# 90 angle with marching cubes algorithm - interpolating function

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, marching-cubes

I am implementing [Marching Cubes Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes). Let say that I have 3D image which is similar to that draw [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Akrj.jpg). When I use MC algorithm I got something like this: [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnSa3.png) 
 Everywhere where angle is ~ 90 degrees MC algorithm approximate that elements too (It follows from interpolating function but I am especially interested in disable approximating everywhere where angle is ~ 90 degrees). 
So instead of [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leq7m.png), I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ4g4.png) (but only where angle ~ 90, everywhere else I expect normal approximation (classic from MC algorithm).

### Current interpolating function

I used **signed distance function** (SDF).

```
Vector3 interpolate(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, float sdf1, float sdf2)
{
    float offset;
    float d = sdf2-sdf1;
    if(fabs(delta) < 1e-5)
    {
        offset = 0.5;
    }else
    {
        offset = (1e-5 - sdf1)/delta
    }

    return Vector3(v1+offset*(v2-v1));
}
```

### Possible solution

One of the solutions is to set smaller size for cubes (voxels). But I can't do that due to performance. So I think that the key is interpolating function.

Comment: The problem with Marching Cubes is that you will never get corners or edges if they are inside a cell, no matter how good your interpolation is. And things can get unstable if they are not. Take a look at *dual contouring*. DC can preserve sharp features, but you need the derivatives of the field.

Comment: But generally I need MC because I need to approximate a lot of real things which are round not sharp.

Comment: You can also try to refine the cube size adaptively in areas where you deem it necessary. However, it becomes a bit tricky to keep the result consistent.